# NextJs display PDF with react-pdf: MissingPDFException

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-pdf, raw-loader

I want to display a PDF file from within the public folder in my next application using `react-pdf` but I keep getting the PDF not found error- here's my setup:

```js
// pdf component
import { pdfjs, Document, Page } from "react-pdf";
import pdf from '../../public/document.pdf';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
    'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js',
    import.meta.url,
  ).toString();
// pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;

const PDFViewer = () => (
    <Document  file={pdf}>
        <Page />
    </Document>
)
```

I imported this component for use in my main component like this:

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const PDFViewer = dynamic(() => import('@/components/PDFViewer'), { ssr: false })

export default function Main() {
    return (
        <div>
            <PDFViewer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

In the `next.config.js` I try to config `raw-loader` package to load PDF file like this:

```js
const nextConfig = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
             test: /\.(pdf)$/i,
             loader: 'file-loader',
             options: {
                 name: './public/document.pdf'
             }
        })
    }
    return config
}
```

The folder structure looks like this:

- project

  - components
  - pages
  - public

    - document.pdf
  - types
  - next.config.js

And here's the message I'm getting in the console:

Warning: MissingPDFException: Missing PDF "http://localhost:3000/_next/public/document.pdf".

How can this be rectified?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I decide to fix it without using the react-pdf. I modified the webpack to this on the next.config.js:

```
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(pdf)$/,
      type: "asset/resource",
    });

    return config;
  },
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And since Next.js does not recognize pdf files I also created a file called types.d.ts and added:

`declare module "*.pdf";`

I hope it helps